# Why @PreAuthorize principal is String and not UserDetails?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have method annotated with @PreAuthorize that uses custom bean

```java
@PreAuthorize("@preAuthUtils.test(authentication)")
public void method(){
    ...
}
```

That bean does nothing just printing out the auth and user (principle)

```java
@Component(value = "preAuthUtils")
public class PreAuthUtils {
        public boolean test(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken x) {
                System.out.println("type: " + x.getClass().getSimpleName());
                System.out.println("string: " + x.toString());
                final var user = x.getPrincipal();
                System.out.println("type: " + user.getClass().getSimpleName());
                System.out.println("string: " + user.toString());
                return true;
        }
}
```

Output (after request)

```json
type: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
string: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=johndoe, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER, ROLE_CUSTOMER]]

type: String
string: johndoe
```

The question is why the user is type of String? and not my custom "DefaultUserDetails" class that implements UserDetails?

Because I need to get the id and info about user to make decisions wheather to authenticate or restrict the user, i spent 6 hours i just want to cry

Comment: Are you saving the `DefaultUserDetails` anywhere in the security context earlier? [Here's](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-userdetailsservice) a part of the docs that may be helpful.

Comment: The principal for a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` is a `String` as that is what is used to identify the user (next to the password).

Comment: @M.Deinum Is my understanding correct? When it autneticates the user it loads it from the database using `loadUserByUsername` and it returns DefaultUserDetails (my custom object)? it uses that object for authentication and then when I request principal why is it just returns me the `Username`, I need DefatulUserDetails, should I quiery database once again to get that or is there a better solution to get DefaultUserDetails insteadof Username?

Comment: When the default `DaoAuthenticationProvider` is used, and it is you just pass in a custom `UserDetailsService` it will always use the `username` as the `principal`. You can check the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find out.

This all due to my JWT filter that actually authenticates the user...

Here the principal is the userDetails (IN WAS STRING ..)

```
                final var authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, null, authorities);

                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(context));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```